# Uses of stack while calling empty recursive funcion in C

Tags: c, recursion, stack

Here is a simple C recursive program.

```
void func(void)
{
   func();
}

int main()
{
   func();
   return 0;
}
```

1. Does this program use the stack in every call of func()
2. If yes, What does it stores in stack?

Comment: It uses more stack than you have. It stores the return address of each recursive call.

Comment: That depends entirely on how smart the compiler is. This can easily be optimized to a tail call, in which case new data doesn't need to be pushed to the stack (in this case a tail call will be an unconditional loop). If it's not optimized like that, then at least the return address needs to be pushed on each call.

Comment: @ThomasJager I've been sitting here thinking about that. The compiler is allowed to optimize such that the result is indistinguishable. So I suppose the compiler is allowed to assume that the stack is an infinite size, because there is no requirement for there to be an actual stack anyway.

Comment: Here it is simply optimized into an infinite loop: https://godbolt.org/z/vTo7aaarW

Comment: Which in fact makes me think that infinite recursion should be considered a UB, because the actual behavior would depend on the optimizations applied.

Comment: (to an extent it is true for *any* recursion...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its not a terribly big program, id suggest compiling it, and running it and checking if youll get a stack overflow, okay argh....
I just tested it:

with /Od it returned resulted in overflow

with /O2 it also resulted in overflow, returning 3221225725

Tested on compiler explorer MSVC V19. latest

--what does it store in the stack?
The instruction pointer / Program Counter.
How else would the program know where to return to?

--whether optimized or not, the only change was the size of the function,
it wont optimize the function away. Or, MSVC 19.latest wouldnt.
If you find a compiler that does, that would be great for those virtual function calls to non-nothingness, which i believe is one of the critiques against them.

Comment: Sure it won't optimize the function away, because it does not terminate. It could replace it with an infinite loop though, as it does here: https://godbolt.org/z/vTo7aaarW

Comment: it will not store anything on the stack even using msvc. https://godbolt.org/z/oTT64PnoK

Answer (score 0):

1. C standard does not know anything about the stack. So generally speaking this question does not have an answer.
2. This function calls itself at the end of its execution. It is called tail recursion (very specific case) and most modern optimising compilers will optimise it to an infinitive loop (assuming optimisations enabled).
3. Most implementations use the stack. Recursive functions (except tail recursion ones) will create a new stack frame on every call.